# AWS boto3 how to improve performance in querying DynamoDB

Tags: query-optimization, boto3, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query  items based on certain keys as seen below. This is used in live streaming event processing where Dynamodb supposed to query the result quickly, but sometimes it seems to be a lengthy process and not returning item quickly

```
pk="some pk value"
filter1="some filter 1"
filter2="somefilter2"
table= aws_dynamodb_table
query= table.query(
   KeyConditionExpression=Key("pk").eq(pk),
   FilterExpression=Attr("filtervalue1").eq(filter1)
& Attr("fitlervalue2").eq(filter2)
result=query["Items"]
```

so is there any way to improve the query?
Appreciated if anybody can give your input on this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of facts defining your query performance such as

your partition keys, sort keys
Indexes use
Read capacity units available.
Amount of data
Memory allocation of the application.

Just go through follow and design your schema and the table based on your use case

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html

Answer (score -1):

`query` scans enitre table. You should consider using [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html) instead. Depending on your exact requirements, you may need to setup [GSI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) to make it viable solution.